# How does half of the dimension give the number of layers of NxN matrix?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, language-agnostic

Assume a matrix of dimension N*N
It seems that to figure out the layers it is composed of the number of them is N/2 but although I can verify it, somehow I can not conceptually connect how does the half of the N gives this layer number.
Example:
4x4 => 4/2 = 2 layers

```
x x x x  
x x x x  
x x x x 
x x x x
```

layers:

```
x x x x  
x     x    x  x  
x     x    x  x  
x x x x
```

[image]

Can someone help me unblock on this?

Comment: What does "layer" mean?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: if you check the second snippet under layers you can see that the right small square appears "extracted" from the bigger on the left. So it is like onion peels. Does this make sense?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth:I updated post. I hope it helps

Comment: Ok, so if you have K layers, how many edges do you have left to right?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth:What do you mean by "edge".How many edges are in my example?

Answer (score 2):

### For even `N`

Focus on a middle row of the matrix. The layers in the following example (`N=6`) are denoted with `x`, `y`, and `z` for clarity.

```
x x x x x x
x y y y y x
x y z z y x <- For example, this row
x y z z y x
x y y y y x
x x x x x x
```

Because you're in the middle, you will go through every layer. In fact, you'll "enter" every layer once and "exit" that layer later. Each time you enter or exit a layer, there is one element of the matrix. For instance, in the above example, going from left to right we have:

```
x: enter layer x
y: enter layer y
z: enter layer z
z: exit layer z
y: exit layer y
x: exit layer x
```

As you can see, we traversed `N` elements on the row, and each layer needs to be entered and exited, so we deduce that there are `N/2` layers.

### For odd `N`

If `N` is odd, the reasoning is mostly the same, except that the innermost layer (which is just one element) is "entered" and "exited" at the same time. The number of layers is `(N+1)/2`. We can derive this by temporarily ignoring the innermost layer. The number of elements in the row (ignoring the innermost layer) is `N-1`, we divide by 2 to get the number of layers (ignoring the innermost layer), and we add 1 (to account for the innermost layer). Then `(N-1)/2 + 1 = (N+1)/2`.

Comment: Nice. With integer arithmetic you could write (N+1) / 2 for both cases, so that you don't have to check if the number is odd or even.